# Will I be able to do more quests?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Just recently, the Imperial Mission spot just says: You've done all of the quests!. Is there really nothing I can do, or is there something I must do, like wait a certain amount of time or build more Imperial levels?

Answer (score 2):

More quests might of might not be added to the game through future updates. Since many features of the game say `Coming Soon!` i guess that there might be some other quests but no one can know for sure since no official statement has been made on the subject.

Comment: Yes, tiny tower adds a new floor for each skill and three residential floors at given intervals, so I think it's safe to assume the same here, potentially with a few more imperial levels and hopefully support for endless imperial missions.